# Taylor's Theorem Example Problem

Tags: real-analysis

> $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $x\rightarrow\sqrt{1+x}$. How good is taylor approx. of $f$ by $P_1(x)$ at $x_0=0$ if $|x|\le0.01$?

So far I have found this:
$$P_1(x) = \frac{x}{2}+1,\quad x\in\mathbb{R}.\quad R_1(x) = \frac{f^{\prime\prime}(\xi)}{2!}(x-x_0)^2.$$
$$\text{Thm:}\quad f:[0,x]\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\exists\xi\in(0,x)s.t.R_1(x)=-\frac{x^2}{8\sqrt{(1+\xi)^3}}.$$

now at this part my lecture has said:

> Note: $1+\xi\ge0.99$.

I don't understand this. If $\xi\in(0,x)$ and $|x|\le0.01$ then $1+\xi\ge1$. Where did my lecturer get o.99 from?

Comment: If $x < 0$, then $\xi \in (x,0)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer this still doesn't explain where 0.99 came from?

Comment: Pick $x = -0.01$. Then $1 + \xi \in (0.99,1)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer oh I see! so because of the modulus it will always be larger then 0.99